# node.js exec sql file

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js

I have a sql file that contains:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aodb;
CREATE TABLE aodb (lowid INT, highid INT, lowql INT, highql INT, name VARCHAR(150), icon INT);
INSERT INTO aodb VALUES (275403, 275403, 1, 1, '"A History of Rubi-Ka" by Prof. Arthur B. Diggins', 136331);
```

It has about 275k inserts, is there a way I can use it with node? I need a way to create that table and insert the data from inside a node file w/o any kind of interaction from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your MySql database with any [Node.js MySql client](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/), read SQL from the file (using [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)) and [execute](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#performing-queries) it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question today, here is my final solution:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec('mysql -u<your_user> -p<your_password> < your_file.sql', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```